# ReportViewer won't bind

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I've got a `ReportViewer` control in an ASCX like so:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer 
   Height="100%" 
   Width="100%" 
   ID="ReportViewer1" 
   runat="server" 
   AsyncRendering="False"
    Font-Names="Verdana" 
   Font-Size="8pt" 
   WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
   WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" 
   OnDataBinding="ReportViewer1_DataBinding" 
   OnDisposed="ReportViewer1_Disposed" 
   OnInit="ReportViewer1_Init" 
   OnLoad="ReportViewer1_Load" 
   OnReportError="ReportViewer1_ReportError">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

And in the page load of the containing ASCX:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
int draftID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["DraftID"]);
MyTableAdapter adapter = new MyTableAdapter();
var table= adapter.GetData(draftID);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/MyReport.rdlc");
var reportDataSource = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource("MyDataSource", (System.Data.DataTable)table);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

I'm reasonably certain I have the web config set up properly.  In the `compilation` tag:

```
    <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </buildProviders>
```

And in the `handlers` tag (just the handler, for brevity):

```
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

The table from the generated adapter gets filled, and at first blush, looks correct.  I set breakpoints on the events listed, and it will be initialized, load, but never bind, leading me to believe I've missed something obvious.

Any ideas?

Comment: what about the source of reportDataSource ? did you checked while debuging?

Comment: Your code looks fine at a glance. Verify that you added the http handler to the correct section. This varies depending your version of IIS and asp.net pipeline mode.

Comment: @Nithesh - `reportDataSource` appears right.  The data from the datatable is getting into the datasource just fine.  @nunespascal - I added it to configuration/system.webserver/handlers - seemed like the most logical place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much experimentation, I ended up starting over from scratch.  I think what happened was I had used Report Builder 3 to build the report, and then tried to convert the RDL to an RDLC.  I've looked at the differences, and they're small but evidently significant.  I was able to salvage virtually all of my work with simply copy/pasting from the original RDL to a new RDLC with the correct data sources defined.  Thanks for the comments and help.